# How to get multiple child value from realtime database and set as assign reference to write data in fiAndroidstudio

Tags: firebase

Hi how can I get multiple child values and assign as a reference for firebase database,

If I get 10 values ,I need to separate those 10 values and I need to assign thoose 10 values as a reference for firebase

If user write data that will be sent to particular 10 values of another user's, these 10 users
How can I do..

In database look like
Ref  (New)
Child (Timestamp num)
Child  (New1: value 1234)
Child  (Timestamp num)
Child (New2: value 23455)
I need to get  child value of new1 and new2. And then I need to assign thoose values separately to point reference like

In database
Ref  ( Getnew)
Child   ( Timestamp num)
Child   (Mcode: value 1234)
Child   (Timestamp num)
Child (Mcode: value 23455)

I need to point to this ref Mcode and set value
How can I do this...

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to accomplish or what you're struggling with. To learn how to read and write to Firebase, this is probably the best place to start: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write. If you ran into problems implementing the use-case, it's much more likely that we can help if you show the [minimal, complete/standalone code that reproduces where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Show us what you have already tried, and tell us what exactly doesn't work the way you expect.